# MCMC software to sample from posteriors of unusual probability distributions

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior

Is there a library, or package---preferably in (but not restricted to) python or R---that let you easily sample from the posterior of "*exotic*" distributions, i.e. distributions that are not commonly used (like Gaussian, Gamma, Poisson,...) and/or that do not have a closed form conjugate prior?

For instance, for the [Gompertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_distribution) distribution one can put a Gamma prior on the scale and exploit conjugacy, but is it implemented in some software already? On the other hand, you cannot even do that for a Beta, right?

As an example of a good package, I am looking at [`MCMC4extremes`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMC4Extremes/) in R, which contains routines to sample from the posteriors of a Gumbel and Generalized Pareto distribution. Do you know something analogous that incorporates more uncommon distributions?

Comment: A software like Stan is supposed to take an arbitrary distribution as input and run an HMC as output.

Answer (score 0):

PyMC for python [lists distributions](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/continuous.html) that can be handled. Gompertz doesn't look to be in there, but you can specify a likelihood and have it do slice sampling I believe.